# How to write firebase query that return all accessible objects for an endpoint?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have created an firebase project witch has user and data endpoints and data has an author variable on which rule set is hanging.

The rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
      "data":{
        "$data":{
        ".read":"auth.uid === data.child('author').val()"
        }
      },
      "users": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read":"auth.uid === $uid"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I was able to make that it is possible to access each object separately yet I do not know how to form a query that display all accessible objects under data.

The data structure:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "45464656" : {
      "answers" : [ 0, 1, 5, 3, 2 ],
      "author" : "twitter:5555"
    },
    "46456456" : {
      "answers" : [ 5, 3, 2, 4, 2 ],
      "author" : "twitter:5555"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "twitter:5555" : {
      "name" : "Jhon",
      "regDate" : 6546546546,
      "snmae" : "Boom"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there some kind of filtering needed to do this or have I formed the access rules incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Firebase queries/security rules as a filter. From the [Firebase documentation on security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter):

> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail completely.

Since you're not granting read access at the `data` level, your query (which presumably starts at `data`) will fail.

Comment: According to the same documentation data should be flat.
So have I made a mistake in data structure or rules.
Because I  think data structure is OK yet I can not think of a way to set access for data in such a way only user data would be available also how to filter correctly.

Comment: You should prefer flattened data, but there is no "must" or "absolute" in data architecture. Here, you'll have to accept a tradeoff between the advantages to flattened data and the limitations of the current iteration of security rules. One alternative to achieve both is to use and index. See [creating data that scales](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-indices).